# Azure SAS Token for a specific file to be uploaded ? With Read And Expiry Time (JAVA)

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, sas-token

I have `BlobServiceAsyncClient`

Used `TenantID`, `clientID`, `ClientSecret`, `ContainerName` for creating the `blobContainerAsyncClient`.

Uploading file as

```
blobContainerAsyncClient.getBlobAsyncClient(fileName).upload(.........);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code

**creates a Shared Access Signature with Read only permission and available only for the next 10 minutes.**

```
public string CreateSAS(string blobName)

{
    var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ContainerName);

    // Create the container if it doesn't already exist
    container.CreateIfNotExists();

    var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

    var sas = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
    {
        Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.READ,
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
    });

    return sas;
}
```

Please refer this document for more information: https://tech.trailmax.info/2013/07/upload-files-to-azure-blob-storage-with-using-shared-access-keys/